# Uploading file to sharepoint server

Tags: c#, sharepoint, uploading

I need to upload files from my  PC to a remote sharepoint server, I have an application with the following code :

```
 using (SPSite oSite = new SPSite(_serverPath))
                {
                    using (SPWeb oWeb = oSite.OpenWeb())
                    {
                        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(txtFileUpload.Text))
                            throw new FileNotFoundException("File not found.", txtFileUpload.Text);

                        SPFolder myLibrary = oWeb.Folders[documentLibraryName];

                        //Prepare to upload ::
                        Boolean replaceExistingFiles = true;
                        String fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(txtFileUpload.Text);
                        FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(txtFileUpload.Text);

                        //Upload document ::
                        SPFile spfile = myLibrary.Files.Add(fileName, fileStream, replaceExistingFiles);

                        //Commit ::
                        myLibrary.Update();
                    }
                }
```

Now I have referenced the dll file "Microsoft.SharePoint" by copy the file from the server where sharepoint is installed (as my PC that running the uploading application is not installing sharepoint) when i try to run the application i got the following error :

**"Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Library, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."**

So how can i solve this problem although i don't have sharepoint installed at my PC and i can't install it?

Thanks in advance, Hope my question is to be clear!.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use visual studio to develop Sharepoint Solutions on client machine with Server Object Model. Please check - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231582.aspx.

However you can develop using Client Object model on the client machine by referencing `Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client` and `Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.Runtime` from sharepoint server.

You can check this article to see how you can do the same using Client object model - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/103503/How-to-upload-download-a-document-in-SharePoint-20

also http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sridhara/archive/2010/03/12/uploading-files-using-client-object-model-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am using the cod sample in the link you supported but still not working issuing errors like "Cannot contact site ********" and when i write the root URL it give the following error "server error 500 internal server error" how can i solve it?

Comment: I am using the .net 3.5 and build 64 bit and still not working at my side i have the same problem how can is olve it?

Comment: @Ahmy are you using client object model? and referencing the dlls mentioned above?

Comment: yes i am referencing "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client" and "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime"

Comment: As I am not sure of your context in entirety, please check if these might be helpful - http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010setup/thread/af64081d-3f90-4515-80c8-55515447854f  and http://thuansoldier.net/?p=1649

Comment: Nice i have fixed it, it was authentication problem not more

Comment: @Shabrawy - Can you post your solution for the authentication problem - perhaps add it as another answer here below.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a security token from a user who has access to write to the library (from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/53454/how-to-upload-document-and-update-properties-in-on.html)):

```
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate ()
        {
            SPUserToken token;
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://sp/sites/dev/"))
            {
                token = site.RootWeb.EnsureUser(@"i:0#.w|contoso\jerry").UserToken;
            }
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://sp/sites/dev/", token))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    Byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\passwords.txt");
                    SPFolder myLibrary = web.Folders["DocVersion"];
                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                    SPFile spfile = myLibrary.Files.Add("pwd.txt", bytes, true);
                    spfile.ListItemAllFields["Title"] = "TestTitle";
                    spfile.ListItemAllFields.SystemUpdate();
                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                }
            }
        });
```